# Make my JavaScript code neater

Tags: javascript, json, performance, google-chrome

Basically this is a code for a shoe website, where as soon as the page is loaded, the script runs and automatically adds the shoe of the proper size to your cart.

skuAndSize stands for the variable the website uses for their shoe size. the selectIndex value of 7 corresponds to size 10.

```
var size_i_want = "10";
var how_many = 1;

function addToCart()
{
  var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
  function setSizeValue()
   {
       document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].selectedIndex = 7;
    }
   if(sizesList != undefined)
    {
      setSizeValue();
      document.getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart")[0].click();
    }
  else
    {
     setTimeout("addToCart()", 5);
    }
 }
setTimeout("addToCart()", 5);
```

Is there any way I can modify this code to make it run faster? It is input via chrome extension, and here is the manifest.json file, although I don't think that it will affect the speed of the program, but I could be wrong:

```
{
    "name": "shoe_program",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "contentSettings"
    ],

    "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "SneakerATC extension [SIZE-10]"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*.nike.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "testing.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this code needs to run faster?  Is the bottleneck actually in this code?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I need to make this code faster because I want the shoe to be added to my cart as fast as possible, so I can get it before other people. (this program is for limited edition shoe releases)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the changes that could make to this (assuming you have posted all of the code for the app) are going to give you very marginal gains. Probably nothing noticeable. However, you could call `.selectedIndex` on `sizeList` inside your `setSizeValue` function. You cache `document.getElementsByName("sizeAndSku") [0]` yet, rather than using the cached variable inside your `setSizeValue` function, you call it again. This requires the execution of the the method `.getElementsByName` again.

Since you already have that value cached inside `sizeList`, you could just use `sizeList[0].selectedIndex=7` inside your `setSizeValue` function.

You are not going to get any really beneficial increase in speed but, at least you have one less function call. I think in any practical application it won't really make a difference but that should give you at least something.